# How to loop the backup logic

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I loop the below logic?

This logic needs to run for every week. For example, in 1st week in source folder I have a files and folder called stack.txt, webmethods, profiles so when I ran the logic all these files are taken backup to the destination folder. In 2nd week in source folder extra directory added e.g., Kafka

So now when the logic runs it should not take backup completely, only the newly added things, like Incremental backup

```
#!/bin/bash

# What to backup. 
Integrationserver="/home/ec2-user/source"

# Where to backup to.
dest="/home/ec2-user/destination"


# Create archive filename.
#date=$(date +%F)
IS=source
hostname=$(hostname -s)
#archive_file="$hostname-$IS-$date.tar.gz"
archive_file="$hostname-$IS.tar.gz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $Integrationserver to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar --exclude=/home/ec2-user/source/logs* --exclude=/home/ec2-user/source/TC*  -zcf $dest/$archive_file $Integrationserver

# Print end status message.
echo
echo "Backup finished"
date
```

Comment: It's a job for `cron`

Comment: Do you really mean _run for every week_, or do you mean _run once a week_?

Comment: @Ivan,of course  It's a job for cron. But my question is how to do the incremental backup with above logic instead of taking backup everytime.

Comment: @user1934428, I mean run once a week .. Every 7th day of month.

Comment: Scheduling a job is not a programming problem, and therefore not suitable for Stackoverflow. This would be better asked at [su]. Also, tools for incemental backups can be discussed there (`rsync` comes to my mind, but `tar` also has an option for incremental backups - I just haven't used it yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the flag `-G` to **GNU tar** for incremental backup, as commented by [user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428).

Actually **GNU tar** has two options for incremental backups, [GNU Tar documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Incremental-Dumps.html#:%7E:text=Incremental%20backup%20is%20a%20special,restored%20when%20extracting%20the%20archive).